# Freeze Header in excel using itextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, itext

I am using iTextSharp to convert gridview in excel, But i want to freeze some rows in excel file that is repeated in every page. Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you "using iTextSharp to convert gridview in excel"? Do you have an ASP.Net gridview bound to Excel spreadsheet and you are taking the rendered HTML and passing that to iTextSharp to convert to PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: To freeze the top row:

Click on the View tab.

Click on Freeze Panes from the ribbon to open the features drop down list.

Click on Freeze Top Row option in the list.
.
A black border should appear beneath row 1 in the worksheet indicating that the area above the line has been "frozen".

Scroll down through the worksheet. If you scroll far enough, the rows below row 1 will begin disappearing while row 1 will stay on the screen.